# Flex viewNavigator and swipe : delay between gesture and effective swipe

Tags: flex4, air

I'm developing right now an iOS mobile application using Flash Builder and last SDK. 
i'm using a viewNavigator and handle gestureswipe event to push and pop views on it.
It seems that there is a noticeable delay between the gesture and the effective swipe animation. I think that this is because Flex create a new instance of the view each time your push it, so is there a way to effectively manage a view cache and/or force the view to be reused between push/pop (and so without crippling the memory management on a mobile device..)

Answer (score 0):

View has destructionPolicy. default "auto" means to create it every time